# Override implicit resetnumbers when using Biblatex's prefixnumbers

Tags: biblatex

I have to use multiple bibliographies, but some of those should share the same number prefix. Biblatex allows to set prefixnumbers, but this implicitly enforces resetnumbers. This results in multiple usage of a label, since the numbering is resetted at each printbibliography call.
The following example illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
  @Misc{A,
    author       = {A Author},
    title        = {Title},
    year         = 2013,
  }

  @Misc{B,
    author       = {B Buthor},
    title        = {Title},
    year         = 2013,
  }

  @Misc{C,
    author       = {C Cuthor},
    title        = {Title},
    year         = 2013,
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,defernumbers,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA2}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catB}
\addtocategory{catA1}{A}
\addtocategory{catA2}{B}
\addtocategory{catB}{C}

\begin{document}
  \cite{A} supposed to be [A1]\\
  \cite{B} supposed to be [A2]\\
  \cite{C} supposed to be [B1]

  \section{Part A1}
  \printbibliography[category=catA1,prefixnumbers={A}]

  \section{Part A2}
  \printbibliography[category=catA2,prefixnumbers={A}]%resetnumbers=false does not work here

  \section{Part B}
  \printbibliography[category=catB,prefixnumbers={B}]
\end{document}
```

How can I tell Biblatex to NOT reset the numbering when printing the second bibliography?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible, and "hackish", way to do this is to use the `biblatex` ability to (re)define different `bibliography` environments.

Thus one can create two `bibliography` environments: one for the A prefix publications, and the second for the B publications (the solution use `enumitem` package, i.e., `\usepackage{enumitem}`, to help with the redefinition of the `bibliography` environments as `enumerate`, and its ability to resume numeration over different `enumerate`s)

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{enumerate}[series=bib,resume=bib,label=A\arabic*.,ref=A\arabic*]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item\label{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibenvironment{bbiblio}
  {\begin{enumerate}[label=B\arabic*.,ref=B\arabic*]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item\label{\thefield{entrykey}}}
```

Notice that we have to define how the label of the enumerate appears and also the format of the references (`ref`).  This solution  also requires to redefine the various citation commands. For `\cite` a possible redefinition is

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  [\mkbibbrackets]
  {}
  {\ref{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {\addcomma\addspace}
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\addcomma\addspace\printfield{postnote}}}
```

Similar definitions are needed for other cite commands. A better way would be to redefine the appropriate `bibmacro`s.

The final step is to call the bibliography with the desired bibliography environment using the `env` option (this it not required for `bibliography`).

```
\section{Part A1}
\printbibliography[category=catA1]

\section{Part A2}
\printbibliography[category=catA2]

\section{Part B}
\printbibliography[category=catB,env=bbiblio]
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Of course I would prefer Biblatex to keep track of a per-prefix-numbering automatically, but this gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer breaks several things, e.g., the conversion of consecutive numbers into ranges for the `numeric-comp` style. Since version 2.9a of biblatex, the option `resetnumbers` accepts a number. This allows a less hackish solution using a counter for each part:

```
\newcounter{BibA}
\setcounter{BibA}{1}
\newcounter{BibB}
\setcounter{BibB}{1}
```

The number of entries in a bibliography can be obtained using the following hooks:

```
\newcounter{NumberOfBibEntries}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{NumberOfBibEntries}{0}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\stepcounter{NumberOfBibEntries}}
```

The part counters can then be updated after each invocation of `\printbibliography` and used as an argument to `resetnumbers` in the following bibliographies:

```
\section{Part A1}
\printbibliography[category=catA1,prefixnumbers={A}]
\addtocounter{BibA}{\value{NumberOfBibEntries}}

\section{Part A2}
\printbibliography[category=catA2,prefixnumbers={A}, resetnumbers=\number\value{BibA}]
\addtocounter{BibA}{\value{NumberOfBibEntries}}

\section{Part B}
\printbibliography[category=catB,prefixnumbers={B}]
\addtocounter{BibB}{\value{NumberOfBibEntries}}
```

It is probably best to wrap this in a macro like

```
\newcommand{\myprintbibliography}[2][]{%
    \printbibliography[#1 ,prefixnumbers={#2}, resetnumbers=\number\value{Bib#2}]%
    \addtocounter{Bib#2}{\value{NumberOfBibEntries}}%
}
```

This full document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
    @Misc{A,
        author       = {A Author},
        title        = {Title},
        year         = 2013,
    }

    @Misc{B,
        author       = {B Buthor},
        title        = {Title},
        year         = 2013,
    }

    @Misc{C,
        author       = {C Cuthor},
        title        = {Title},
        year         = 2013,
    }

    @Misc{D,
        author       = {D Duthor},
        title        = {Title},
        year         = 2013,
    }

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,defernumbers,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA2}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catB}
\addtocategory{catA1}{A,B}
\addtocategory{catA2}{C}
\addtocategory{catB}{D}

\newcounter{NumberOfBibEntries}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{NumberOfBibEntries}{0}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\stepcounter{NumberOfBibEntries}}

\newcounter{BibA}
\setcounter{BibA}{1}
\newcounter{BibB}
\setcounter{BibB}{1}

\newcommand{\myprintbibliography}[2][]{%
    \printbibliography[#1 ,prefixnumbers={#2}, resetnumbers=\number\value{Bib#2}]
    \addtocounter{Bib#2}{\value{NumberOfBibEntries}}    
}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    \cite{A, B, C} supposed to be [A1-A3]\\
    \cite{D} supposed to be [B1]\\

    \section{Part A1}
    \myprintbibliography[category=catA1]{A}

    \section{Part A2}
    \myprintbibliography[category=catA2]{A}

    \section{Part B}
    \myprintbibliography[category=catB]{B}

\end{document}
```

The only problem I encountered is related to the necessary `defernumbers` option. As the manual states, sometimes the .aux file has to be deleted to obtain the correct numbering.

Answer (score 1):

With biblatex 3.5+biber 2.6 (both currently in DEV on Sourceforge), this behaviour is finally fixed. It is now possible to override the implicit `resetnumbers` in the normal way (example updated for changes to `prefixnumbers` which moved into the refcontext mechanism with a name change to `labelprefix` in biblatex 3.3):

```
\section{Part A1}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[category=catA1]

\section{Part A2}
\printbibliography[category=catA2, resetnumbers=false]

\section{Part B}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[category=catB]
```