# Multiple Bibliographies, same prefix

Tags: biblatex

My question is exactly the same as here:

[biblatex: multiple bibliographies with same prefix, using resetnumber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238369/biblatex-multiple-bibliographies-with-same-prefix-using-resetnumber)

However, the solution provided by Ulrike Fischer does not seem to work anymore. Has an update of biblatex changed something here and is there a good alternative?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use this code, it still works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316375/29873

Comment: @DG' Would you mind turning your comment into an answer? It is probably not a good idea to close this question as a duplicate of the other question, given that it is specifically about one of the answers. The best way forward here is definitely to use PLK's answer (which definitely still works, I tried it).

Comment: @moewe - Will do (I also tried it, before my comment)

Answer (score 2):

You can use PLK's code from his answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238369/biblatex-multiple-bibliographies-with-same-prefix-using-resetnumber/316375#316375):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics,nussbaum,pines,vangennep,wassenberg}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[keyword=primary, title={primary}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title={secondary}, resetnumbers=false]
\newrefcontext
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary,notkeyword=secondary, title={other}, resetnumbers]

\end{document}
```

[image]